# How to turn a list into a 2x2 array that is understood by contourf

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I was trying to pass values with the dimensions of a created meshgrid into an iterating array that will only contain 3 values in each iteration (X,Y,0). I was treating my variables as 3d vectors so that I can perform the cross product, dot product, and norm functions so that python handles the phi function correctly. The ultimate goal was to create a lagrange contour plot of a 2 body system.

The error I kept running into was:

```
TypeError: Input z must be a 2D array.
```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#initial values
m1=3.0
m2=1.0
a=1.0
n=1.5*a

#x and y evenly spaced gridpoint values
x=np.arange(-n,n,0.01)
y=np.arange(-n,n,0.01)
X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y)

mtot=m1+m2
#the distance from the bodies to the center of mass of the system
x1=-(m2/mtot)*a
x2=(m1/mtot)*a
X1=np.array([x1,0,0])
X2=np.array([x1,0,0])

om=np.sqrt(mtot/(a**3)) #omega term
OM=np.array([0,0,om])

phi=[]
#more arrays
r=np.array([X,Y])
R=np.array([])

#gravitational potential function
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(y)):
        R=np.array([r[0,i,j],r[1,j,i],0])  
        denom1 = np.linalg.norm(R-X1) 
        denom2 = np.linalg.norm(R-X2)
        term1 = -m1/denom1
        term2 = -m2/denom2
        oa=np.cross(R,OM) 
        term3=0.5*np.dot(oa,oa)
        phi.append([term1+term2-term3]) 

#the line below is the formula I am trying to implement with the loop above
#phi= -m1/abs(r-x1)-m2/abs(r-x2)-0.5*(om**2)*r**2

#omitted code where output is saved to a file. 

PHI=np.array(phi)
PHI=np.reshape(PHI,(300,300)) 

phi[phi<-10]=-10

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.contourf(X,Y,phi,20, cmap='jet')
plt.show()
```

The result should generate a contour plot of the effective gravitational potential energy at each gridpoint. [Lagrange Contour Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hGdL.png) Here is what I generated.

Comment: A couple of quick observations.  Accumulating `phi` values with `np.append` is not a good idea.  If you must iteration, accumulate the values in a list with list append.  `X` is (300,300), `r` is then `(2,300,300)`.  `r[i,:]` is then (300,300)` while `r[:,j]` is (2,300)`.  Check the `shape` a lot while debugging; don't guess.

Comment: And the `for i in phi` loop - where's `i` used?

Comment: I switched to a list append and deleted the useless for loop with phi. Not sure why I put it in there in the first place... I am still not sure how to pass in the X,Y coordinates into R. I want the R vector to hold only 1 X coordinate and 1 Y coordinate and overwrite itself with the next X and Y coordinate with each iteration. I'm sorry if I am not explaining myself well and/or not understanding your comment properly. I am not very good at debugging yet...

Comment: I have made some progress (I also updated the question's code). Thank you for pointing me in the right direction hpaulj. The issue I am now encountering is with trying to reshape the 1D array output PHI so that it will be accepted by contourf.

Comment: I finally got it working! I've updated the code and appended a sample output.